# OpenGL float precision makes unexpected differece

Tags: c++, opengl, precision, glm-math

I have a function which rotates the camera around the player by yaw and pitch angles.

```
void Camera::updateVectors() {
    GLfloat radius = glm::length(center - position);
    position.x = cos(glm::radians(this->yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    position.y = sin(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    position.z = sin(glm::radians(this->yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    position *= radius;
    this->front = glm::normalize(center - position);
    this->right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->front, this->worldUp));
    this->up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->right, this->front));
    lookAt = glm::lookAt(this->position, this->position + this->front, this->up);
}
```

When I move the player the camera should moves with it by adding a translation vector to both the center and position of the camera:

```
void Camera::Transform(glm::vec3& t) {
    this->position += t;
    this->center += t;
}
```

Vefore moving the player the camera rotation works fine and the player movement also works fine but once I try to rotate the camera after player moving it start to change position unexpected.

[image]

After making some debugging I noticed that the radius which Is calculated at first line which is the distance between center and position of the camera like 49.888889 or 50.000079 and due to the initialized values it should be 50.0, this very small difference makes the result unexpected at all.
so how could I treat this float precision or is there a bug in my code or calculations.

Edit:
 position the player depends on its yaw and pitch and update the center of the camera

```
GLfloat velocity = this->movementSpeed * deltaTime;
if (direction == FORWARD) {
    glm::vec3 t = glm::vec3(sin(glm::radians(yaw)), sin(glm::radians(pitch)), cos(glm::radians(yaw))) * velocity;
    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, t);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
    glm::vec3 f(matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]);
    f *= velocity;
    scene->getDefCamera()->Transform(f);
}
if (direction == BACKWARD) {
    glm::vec3 t = glm::vec3(sin(glm::radians(yaw)), 0.0, cos(glm::radians(yaw))) * velocity;
    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, -t);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
    glm::vec3 f(matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]);
    f *= velocity;
    f = -f;
    scene->getDefCamera()->Transform(f);
}
```

Comment: lookAt = glm::lookAt(this->position, this->position + this->front, this->up); this->front is a normalized vector. you are adding a small amount to your camera position i think. glm::lookat second argument should be the world position of the object, not sure ...

Comment: put center instead of position+front it might help, don't know

Comment: the second vector in lookAt function parameters is the view direction and center and position+front in the save vector direction so the result is the same

Comment: yes you are right, my bad. I don't know how weird your camera behave. if you move on the "x" axis the right and up vector shouldn't change. Try to not update thoose and look if there are some bugs or print previous and next version. Maybe the problem come from the cross product which gives you opposite direction.

Comment: the problem as in noticed from gloat precision which makes very small difference causes the result, this comes once I change the center and position of the camera

Comment: Ok, if it's small differences and not such a bug deal. You should maybe keep the center - position and fix it as a constant. this way you will not gain error over time.

Comment: they can't be fixed, they always change with player movment

Comment: maybe the vectors change but the length could vary from different state where each of thoose states has a given value. If i were you i would not apply formula from spherical coordonates with pitch, yaw roll etc... And use glm::translate and glm::rotate with vec3 containing your angle and position.

Comment: maybe somehting like  vec3 posRelative = glm::rotate(center - pos, vec3(pitch, yaw, roll)); position = center + posRelative

Comment: Please add your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44904587/4) as a distinct answer, in the answer section, do not edit the question with solved see: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution simply is making transformations on the camera view matrix instead of making it by `lookAt` function
 first initialize the camera

```
void Camera::initCamera(glm::vec3& pos, glm::vec3& center, GLfloat yaw, GLfloat pitch) {
    view = glm::translate(view, center-pos);
    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(yaw), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(pitch), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    view = glm::translate(view, pos-center);
}
```

then the rotation function:

```
void Camera::Rotate(GLfloat xoffset, GLfloat yoffset, glm::vec3& c) {
    xoffset *= this->mouseSensitivity;
    yoffset *= this->mouseSensitivity;
    view = glm::translate(view, c );//c is the player position
    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(xoffset), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(yoffset), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    view = glm::translate(view,  - c);
}
```

and the camera move function:

```
void Camera::Translate(glm::vec3& t) {
    view = glm::translate(view, -t);
}
```

and in the player class when the player moves it push camera to move in its direction by this code

```
void Mesh::Move(Move_Directions direction, GLfloat deltaTime) {
GLfloat velocity = 50.0f * this->movementSpeed * deltaTime;
if (direction == FORWARD) {
    glm::vec3 t = glm::vec3(sin(glm::radians(yaw)), sin(glm::radians(pitch)), cos(glm::radians(yaw))) * velocity;
    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, t);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
    glm::vec3 f(matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]);
    f *= velocity;
    scene->getDefCamera()->Translate(f);
}
if (direction == BACKWARD) {
    glm::vec3 t = glm::vec3(sin(glm::radians(yaw)), 0.0, cos(glm::radians(yaw))) * velocity;
    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, -t);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
    glm::vec3 f(matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]);
    f *= velocity;
    f = -f;
    scene->getDefCamera()->Translate(f);
}
if (direction == RIGHT) {
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, (GLfloat) -M_PI * deltaTime, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
if (direction == LEFT) {
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, (GLfloat) M_PI * deltaTime, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        this->m_Entries[i].setModelMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
}
```

thanks for every body helped

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that you're rotating based on a position that is moving. But rotations are based on the origin of the coordinate system. So when you move the position, the rotation is still being done relative to the origin.

Instead of having `Transform` offset the `position`, it should only offset the `center`. Indeed, storing `position` makes no sense; you *compute* the camera's position based on its current center point, the radius, and the angles of rotation. The radius is a property that should be stored, not computed.